# Google Drive as a backend server without asking user to login

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I am trying to build an iOS application that all users sharing the same google drive account. All users will access the same account to download content only. I am the only one who is uploading content to google drive on web. For this case, is it possible to skip the login and auth process for the user? It would be great if I can have the users directly download the content, and hopefully make the login and auth implicitly done by code.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, did you ever get around this problem? I am trying to do the same thing.